# How to show an application from the dock in files?

Tags: installed-programs

I am trying to run an application in the terminal to view the output. Finding the application manually in the file explorer is out of the question. is there a way to view the location of an application in the dock in a file explorer? Relying on the app name is out of the question. For example, I tried `which Google Chrome` or `which Minecraft Launcher` and none of these works, even though both apps are installed.

Comment: Do you mean how to get the path of the executable of the dock apps? I.e. the `Exec=` line of the .desktop file? You can get your favorites apps with `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`.

Comment: Since your example file names contain SPACE characters,  they must be quoted. Try `which "Google Chrome"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal window, assuming the application is named `foobar`, you could:

```
type -p foobar
```

or

```
locate foobar
```

or

```
locate foobar.desktop
```

Comment: I try `locate Minecraft Launcher.desktop`AND `locate Minecraft Launcher` Neither work!

Comment: You have to escape spaces within filenames, otherwise they look like two filenames, neither of which exists. `locate Minecraft\ Launcher`. Or `locate 'Minecraft Launcher'`. Also try `locate --ignore-case minecraft`

Answer (score 1):

To get the location of the application or file from the terminal, you can use the 'which' command, like:

```
which app_name
```

This will return the path of the file. After that, you can open the file explorer (named Files, in Ubuntu), click on the "Other Locations" button on the left side bar, and click on "Computer", which will take you to the root folder ("/"). From there, you can navigate to the path that the 'which' command returned.

Comment: I tried `which Sublime Text` and I got nothing

Comment: If the app has spaces, then surround it with doble quotes `which "Sublime Text"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the files which describe dock icons and desktop icons are typically found inside `/usr/share/applications`. You can probably find it there. In my case, I was looking for vscodium. So I searched for it like this and found it:

```
$ ls /usr/share/applications | grep vs
vscodium.desktop

$ cat /usr/share/applications/vscodium.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VSCodium
GenericName=Code Editor
Exec=/home/forest/Desktop/programs/codium.d/codium
Icon=/home/forest/Desktop/programs/codium.d/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
StartupWMClass="VSCodium"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Source: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-desktop-shortcut/